# Writing on a premade Image

Tags: java, image

http://www.robinswebsitestudio.com/ButtonSamples/buttons.html

The following code does write to a premade image.  The resulting image, though, has significant problems.

- the original png file is a 3D button with Index Transparency and a matte so that the gif file would 
  blend in with the page background color

  the resulting gif file is flat, the matte is gone, and the text doesn’t look smooth.  The resulting 
  file is therefore is not something you would get from Adobe Photoshop or Fireworks and doesn’t look 
  professional.

If anyone has suggestions, I’m all ears. Is it impossible to get a high quality 3D button using Java?

---

```
 String  pathToWeb = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);

   File f = new File(pathToWeb + "activities.png");

   BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(f);

   // Create a graphics which can be used to draw into the buffered image 
  Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics(); 

  g2d.setFont(new Font( "Arial", Font.BOLD, 15 ));       

  //create a string with black
  g2d.setColor(Color.black);

  g2d.drawString("Activities", 40, 40); 

   // Disposes of this graphics context and releases any system resources that it is using.  
   g2d.dispose(); 

   // Save as gif
   File file = new File("myactivities.gif"); 
   ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "gif", file);
```

Comment: Show the PNG and GIF images.

Comment: Yes, as suggested by @NathanielWaisbrot, loading the before/after images to an image share site & linking could be productive.  Also for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - 1) you do realize that GIF is limited to 256 colors and no partial transparency, right? 2) You'll probably need to use rendering hints when painting the string.